# device driver crashes after it is used repetadly by user application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This is my own simple device driver that uses work queue to generate async interrupts on user application. The workqueue reschedules it self (with delay) each time it has been called after giving the async notification to the user application. 
The user application goes is in while after asking the driver for interrupt and waits there. To handle the exit properly, when the user application is terminated using ctrl+c, handle is called that tells driver to unscheduled the task and then closes the driver and exits.

The issue is if I run the user application repetitively for more then 3 times the system freezes with no error on syslog entry. 
Below is the code for driver

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/device.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/stat.h>
#include"ioctrl.h"
#include<linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include<linux/timer.h>
#include<linux/workqueue.h>

#define DEVICE_NAME "myCharDevice"
#define MODULE_NAME "myCharDriver"
#define CLASS_NAME "myCharClass"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("YASH BHATT");
MODULE_VERSION(".01");

static char *bufferMemory;
static int bufferPointer;
static int bufferSize = 15;
static dev_t myChrDevid;
static struct cdev *myChrDevCdev;
static struct class *pmyCharClass;
static struct device *pmyCharDevice;
static wait_queue_head_t waitQueue; 
static int exit_now = 0;
static struct delayed_work *MyTask;
static int in_sleep = 0;
static volatile int wake_up = 5;
int majorNumber = 0;

static int charDriverOpen(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep);
static int charDriverClose(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep);
static ssize_t charDriverWrite(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset);
static ssize_t charDriverRead(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset);
static int charDriverEntry(void);
static void charDriverExit(void);
static long charDriverCtrl(struct file *filep, unsigned int command, unsigned long argument);
static int myfasync(int fd, struct file *fp, int on);
static void send_signal_timerfn(struct work_struct *work);

static struct file_operations fops = 
{
    .open = charDriverOpen,
    .release = charDriverClose,
    .read = charDriverRead,
    .write = charDriverWrite,
    .unlocked_ioctl = charDriverCtrl,
    .fasync = myfasync,
};
static struct fasync_struct *fasyncQueue;

static int __init charDriverEntry()
{
    int returnValue;

    returnValue = alloc_chrdev_region(&myChrDevid, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME); 
    majorNumber = MAJOR(myChrDevid);    
    if (returnValue < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "ERROR : can not aquire major number! error %d",returnValue);
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Aquired Major Number! : %d\n", MAJOR(myChrDevid));

    myChrDevCdev = cdev_alloc();
    if (IS_ERR(myChrDevCdev))
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to allocate space for CharDev struct\n");
        unregister_chrdev_region(myChrDevid, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    cdev_init(myChrDevCdev,&fops);
    myChrDevCdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    pmyCharClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE,CLASS_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(pmyCharClass))
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to Register Class\n");
        cdev_del(myChrDevCdev);
        kfree(myChrDevCdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(myChrDevid, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Class created!\n");

    pmyCharDevice = device_create(pmyCharClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber,0),NULL,DEVICE_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(pmyCharDevice))
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to Register Class\n");
        class_unregister(pmyCharClass);
        class_destroy(pmyCharClass);
        cdev_del(myChrDevCdev);
        kfree(myChrDevCdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(myChrDevid, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Device created!\n");

    returnValue = cdev_add(myChrDevCdev, myChrDevid, 1);
    if (returnValue < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to add chdev \n");
        return -1;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "Now We will create the attribute entry in sysfs\n");
    init_waitqueue_head(&waitQueue);
    MyTask = kmalloc(sizeof(struct delayed_work), GFP_KERNEL);
    INIT_DELAYED_WORK(MyTask, send_signal_timerfn);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit charDriverExit()
{
    device_destroy(pmyCharClass, MKDEV(majorNumber,0));
    class_unregister(pmyCharClass);
    class_destroy(pmyCharClass);
    //unregister_chrdev(majorNumber,DEVICE_NAME);
    cdev_del(myChrDevCdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(myChrDevid, 1);
    kfree(myChrDevCdev);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unmounting module done !\n");
}

static int charDriverOpen(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    if (bufferSize <= 0)
    {
        bufferSize = 15;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "INFO : CHARATER DRIVER OPENED\n");
    bufferMemory = kmalloc(bufferSize,GFP_KERNEL);
    bufferPointer = 0;
    wake_up = 5;
    in_sleep = 0;
    //add_timer(&timer);
    printk(KERN_INFO "timer setup \n");
    return 0;   
}

static int charDriverClose(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    //del_timer(&timer);
    kfree(bufferMemory);
    printk(KERN_INFO "INFO : CHARACTER DRIVER CLOSED\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t charDriverWrite(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk("dummy write\n");
}

static ssize_t charDriverRead(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk("Dummy read");
}
static long charDriverCtrl(struct file *filep, unsigned int command, unsigned long argument)
{
    int returnVal;
    bufferSizeStruct sizeStruct;
    printk(KERN_INFO "INFO: IOCONTROL called\n");
    switch(command)
    {
        case GO_TO_SLEEP:
            printk("Going to sleep \n");
            in_sleep = 1;
            printk("value of wake_up before going to sleep %d\n",wake_up);
            //returnVal = wait_event_interruptible(waitQueue, !wake_up);
            wait_event(waitQueue, !wake_up);
            returnVal = 0xA5A5;
            printk("I have woken up returnVal = %d!\n",returnVal);
            //del_timer(&timer);
            wake_up = 5;
            break;
        case ADD_TO_QUEUE:
            printk("Adding work to queue\n");
            schedule_delayed_work(MyTask, 100);
            exit_now = 0;
            break;
        case REMOVE_TASK_FROM_QUEUE:
            exit_now = 1;
            cancel_delayed_work_sync(MyTask);
            printk("Removing task from queue\n");
            break;
        default:
            printk(KERN_WARNING "WARNING: Invalid IOCTRL ARGUMENT!\n");
            return -1;
    }
    printk("outside the switch already \n");
    return 0;
}

static int myfasync(int fd, struct file *fp, int on)
{
    return fasync_helper(fd, fp, 1, &fasyncQueue);  
}

static void send_signal_timerfn(struct work_struct *work)
{   


    printk(KERN_INFO "timer expired \n");
    kill_fasync(&fasyncQueue, SIGIO, POLL_OUT);
    if (in_sleep == 1)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "in the timer callback with sleep on wake_up : %d\n", wake_up);
        wake_up--;
        if (!wake_up)
            {
                printk(KERN_INFO "now going to wake my self up\n");
                wake_up(&waitQueue);
            }
    }
    if (!exit_now)
        schedule_delayed_work(MyTask, 100);
}

module_init(charDriverEntry);
module_exit(charDriverExit);
module_param(bufferSize, int, S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(bufferSize, "Buffer Memory Size [15]");
```

User application is as follows :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include"ioctrl.h"
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<signal.h>

bufferSizeStruct sizeStruct;
int fp;

void my_notifier(int signo, siginfo_t *sigInfo, void *data)
{
    printf("Signal received from the driver expected %d got %d \n",SIGIO,signo);
}

void my_signal(int p)
{
    ioctl(fp, REMOVE_TASK_FROM_QUEUE );
    close(fp);
    exit(0);
}
int main()
{
    struct sigaction signalInfo;
    int flagInfo;

    signalInfo.sa_sigaction = my_notifier;
    signalInfo.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&signalInfo.sa_mask);

    sigaction(SIGIO, &signalInfo, NULL);
    signal(SIGINT, my_signal);

    int i;
    char c[5];
    fp = open("/dev/myCharDevice",O_RDWR);
    if (fp<0)
        printf("Failed to open\n");

    /*New we will own the device so that we can get the signal from the device*/

    fcntl(fp, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    flagInfo = fcntl(fp, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fp, F_SETFL, flagInfo|FASYNC);
    sleep(5);
    printf("Scheduling work queue\n");
    ioctl(fp, ADD_TO_QUEUE );
    //printf("Sending the drive to sleep for a while \n");
    //ioctl(fp, GO_TO_SLEEP);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I think I am forgetting to disable something and that is loading the kernel.
I am facing the same issue when I was working with timers even tough i had performed del_timer() on each exit. What am I missing here ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a kernel bug. I ran the same program on Linux 4.15 and it works fine but crashes on 4.13.43